# Fixed width td via td-width

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

using AngularJS and/or Bootstrap, is it possible to declare :

```
td-X : {
    min-width: Xpx; 
    max-width: Xpx; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

then

```
<td-320>my fixed column</td-320>
```

or

```
<td class="td-150">my fixed column</td>
```

PS.

I also use Angular [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) if it can help...

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a class `.td-320` and use it in html? using td-320 as an example

Comment: 320 is an example. I would use `td-X`...

Comment: You can't do this with a class, you would have to use style: `style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 320px;"`

Comment: Or lots of CSS styles, which is ugh!

Comment: I want a dynamic declaration, like boostrap `col-xs-X`

Comment: If X is a small list of values then you can define them in css

Comment: Bootstrap isn't dynamic, it's static.

Comment: `col-xs-X` would have to be defined in css for it to work

Comment: I ask about dynamic.

Comment: As dynamic as bootstrap. Unless you put the styles inline, you would need to define them somewhere, there is no connection between the js and css with angular

Comment: I would use it like bootstrap does, but I ask about building a directive or something with AngularJS...

Comment: I'll say again... Bootstrap is not dynamic, it uses percentages. So `col-xs-6` is 50% for example. It's still a static number. If you want 320px, you can only write 320px.

Comment: I didn't say bootstrap is dynamic. I need something dynamic, but to use in HTML like I use bootstrap.

Comment: *I want a dynamic declaration, like boostrap* sounds pretty much like you said Bootstrap is dynamic to me...

Comment: @DavidG you are right. is sounds like this. but let's rather talk about a solution..

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom directive?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fixedWidth', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'fixedWidth': "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      if (!isNaN(scope.fixedWidth)) {
        var widthPx = scope.fixedWidth + 'px';
        element.css('width', widthPx);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td fixed-width="50">50px</td>
        <td fixed-width="100">100px</td>
        <td fixed-width="150">150px</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```